# How to start samsung bixby camera by intent and receive a picture description

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, bixby

Have Samsung Bixby Vision installed on Galaxy S8 phone.

I would like to know, is it possible to start Samsung Bixby camera app by intent (e.g., `Context::startActivityForResult...`) and receive a description of what Bixby camera found out?

Like a description of wine etc.

I'm not interested in the picture, just its description via Bixby vision.

I've browsed Samsung developers forums and didn't find any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Great use case, but that is not supported at the moment.

[image]

More information [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/design-guides/design-principles#bixby-vision)